# is it possible to pass child to ko computed function as parameter

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have two separate knockout observable arrays.  if you call a function in a foreach construct and function is in $root. the element is available to you. however it appears that is not the case for computed functions. Is it possible to make it work for computed functions?  here is a fiddle illustrating the situation.

https://jsfiddle.net/ubvyeba8/1/

or you may run the code snippet below.

```js
function employee(empid, first, last){
  var self = this;
  this.empid = ko.observable(empid);
  this.first = ko.observable(first);
  this.last = ko.observable(last);
}

function model() {
  var self = this;
  this.employees = ko.observableArray('');
  this.employeesThatWorkInHR = ko.observableArray(['1','4','5'])
  this.testComputable = ko.computed(function(emp){
    if (emp){
    return true;
    }else{
    return false;
    }
  },this);
  this.testFunction = function(emp){
    if (emp){
    alert('true');
    }else{
    alert('false');
    }
  }
  
  
}

var mymodel = new model();

$(document).ready(function() {
  ko.applyBindings(mymodel);
  mymodel.employees.push(new employee('1','Fred','Smith'));
  mymodel.employees.push(new employee('2','John','Jones'));
  mymodel.employees.push(new employee('3','Mary','Jane'));
  mymodel.employees.push(new employee('4','Sue','Green'));
  mymodel.employees.push(new employee('5','Terrence','Small'));
});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>


<table class="table">
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th>Id</th>
    <th>First</th>
    <th>Last</th>
    <th>is emp passed to computed</th>
    <th></th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody data-bind="foreach: employees">
  <tr>
    <td data-bind="text: empid"></td>
     <td data-bind="text: first"></td>
     <td data-bind="text: last"></td>
     <td data-bind="text: $root.testComputable"></td>
     <td><button class="btn" data-bind="click: $root.testFunction">
        is emp passed to function
     </button></td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I don't think so, but you could just move the computed down into the employee object to have access to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What are you trying to accomplish by using a computed in this instance? A computed function is used when one value depends on values of other observables, so the computed function will track the dependent values and update accordingly. If what you want is to subscribe to changes in your observable arrays, then you can use a subscription function described [here](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observables.html) (search for 'Explicitly subscribing to observables').

A subscription function does accept the updated value as its function argument, so maybe you can use that for your purposes. A computed function takes no argument (which is why emp is never defined in your example), but you do have 'this' available to you to access other properties within your viewmodel.

Comment: thanks, think you got me on the right track. here is what I did. https://jsfiddle.net/ubvyeba8/19/  I moved the computed into observable array. in the computed I referenced the other observable array. I was a bit surprised I didn't have to do some kind of subscription to make it work but it seems to be working.